# Custom rule for friendly url in dnn

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am struggling with friendly urls in dnn.
I have a profile page:

```
http://localhost/dnn/uProfile/tabid/95/userId/1/Default.aspx
```

which I want to be like:

```
http://localhost/dnn/uProfile/1/username.aspx
```

I have tried to add some rules to `host > friendly url settings` but I don't really understand how to achieve this, or I am trying impossible :) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option for doing something like this is with URLMaster, www.ifinity.com.au